# mvc 3 music store tutorial:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm learning ASP.net MVC 3 with the music store tutorial--but translating the C# into VB. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-2

Jon Galloway says that "ASP.NET MVC’s default routing convention is to treat the segment of a URL after the action method name as a parameter named “ID”.

I have the following code in my StoreController

```
  Function Details(id As Integer) As String
        Return "Store Details, ID= " & i.ToString
    End Function
```

But when I put in the url `http://localhost:53867/store/details/5` I get the following server error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'i' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String
>   Details(Int32)' in 'MvcMusicStore.MvcMusicStore.StoreController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Based on the Galloway description of default ID paramaters above, I would expect this method to take the 5 that comes at the end of the URL as the (default) parameter. Why is it coming out null? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things that I am noticing in your code that you may want to check.

1. In your function body, you are calling i.ToString, but passing in id as parameter
2. Doesn't VB require the ByVal preface to parameters of functions?
3. Is this copy/paste from your project or did you type it?  It sounds like 5 is being assigned to ID which is in the default route, but you are appearing to use i as your parameter, which is null, since it isn't part of the route and you are not passing it as a querystring parameter

Comment: it was a silly error. I had the parameter name as i instead of id, but changed it to id when it was not working. Then i ran the application but it did not rebuild because of the error you pointed out in #1. So it looked like the application was generating the error even when the var was named id. In actuality, I was running a build where the var was named i, so it still did not work. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: @akh2103 - we've all been there, no sweat.  Glad you got it worked out

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VB, but I do work with (among other things) C#.

As far as your error is concerned, I'm wondering how VB is translating the routes? In the link that you have, before you get the "Store Details", there is an example for "/Store/Browse?genre=Disco". Did that work in your app?

I could be wrong, but it looks like this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-vb) will help in the routing issue, particularly Listing 4 *(Index action with nullable parameter)*.

The gist of that is...

```
Function Details(ByVal id? As Integer) As String
  Return "Store Details, ID= " & i.ToString
End Function
```

...might work for you, or at least something like that.

Comment: VB handles routing the same a C#.  The example that you are seeing is because out of the box, there is no route that handles the genre parameter, so it will be a query string value.

Answer (score 0):

the error is that you put **i** instead of **id** , just a misspelled variable name

```
Function Details(ByVal id As Integer) As String
      Return "Store Details, ID= " & id.ToString()
End Function
```